# Need parser for bars

Tags: pine-script

We need to make a code that compares the interval between two indicator curves, and if the interval is greater than n values, it would give a signal to enter the trade. How can i do this? New to pinescript. I don’t understand how I can compare the timeframe value.
I thought that I could somehow solve this problem by checking if the values of the two curves intersect. If they do not intersect for 6 bars, then x = 80, if they intersect, end the cycle by setting the value x = 0

```
b=1
for n=1 to 6
    if k1[n]==k2[n]
        break
    else
        b:=b+1
        continue
x=0
if b==7
    x:=80
else
    x:=0
plot(x, linewidth=3)
```

I would like it to have "b" different meanings, from which I could build on and draw a graph in the future. But for some reason, always b = 6

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("")
k1 = rsi(close, 3)
k2 = rsi(close, 20)
c = cross(k1, k2)
b = barssince(c)
x = b >= 6 ? 80 : 0
plot(x, color = color.red)
// Debugging.
plotchar(c, "c", "•", location.top)
plotchar(b, "b", "", location.top)
plot(k1)
plot(k2)
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of what this does and how it does it to the answer? Thank you.